# Arrow key navigation with ScrollTo jumpy

Tags: jquery, navigation, keyboard, scrollto

I'm using `if (e.keyCode == 40)` to trigger a scrollTo function, but for some reason in chrome its seems to jump up before scrolling, which is really buggy.

I made a jfiddle of my problem ( this only happens on chrome, works fine with firefox.

Make sure to click on the result tab before hitting your down arrow and you will see it jump up and then scroll, same with the up key once on the second slide.

http://jsfiddle.net/vEpS3/9/

If any of you know a way to fix this I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a

```
e.preventDefault();
```

before the scrollTo http://jsfiddle.net/whucg/